# applied PDE equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I'm looking at paper

[image]

The author set $T_t$ to 0 to simplify the problem. How would we proceed to solve the problem if we do not assume that $T_t$ is 0?
Clearly, eqn  (2.7) would just have an extra term, say $\rho_f c_{pf}T_{r}$
What would be a good way to solve this equation and can you give a sense on how much more difficult it is than the previous one?

Comment: As you have a finite domain and the PDE is a linear, inhomogeneous diffusion equation, separation of variables would probably be the way to go.

Comment: is that the best way? are there any other ways/ avenues that one can take?

Comment: after replacing constants by unity and assuming no flux, we arrive at this: $R'S+RS'=R''S$ I've only done simple separation of variables where I get all the, say, R's on one side and the S's on the number. There doesn't seem to be a way to do this here. What am I missing?

Comment: \begin{align} R'S + RS' &= R''S \\ \implies R' + R S'/S &= R'' \\ \implies R'/R + S'/S &= R''/R \\ \implies S'/S &= R''/R - R'/R \end{align}

Comment: I'm confused by the beginning of page 30 https://web.wpi.edu/Pubs/E-project/Available/E-project-050515-101105/unrestricted/FinalReport.pdf The original equation only has thetas yet Laplace introduces r's. The equation they obtained after separation of variables ansatz is similar to yours @mattos, Would I need 3 variables in my case? I don't see a t in Laplace's equation in that form(cylindrical)